# If the first derivative is $0$ at a certain point, is that necessarily a critical point?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So I know the first derivative of a function $f$ must be $0$ (or undefined) at a point $x_0$ for there to be a critical point at $f(x_0)$. But does the converse hold true? i.e. if the first derivative is $0$ is it definitely a critical point?

Thanks

Comment: What is your definition of a critical point?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics)

Comment: I believe it is defined as a point $x_0$ in the domain of a function $f$ such that $f'(x_0)$ is $0$ or undefined?

Comment: Right, it's the *definition*.  All definitions are if and only if.  I don't understand your question.

Comment: I knew that given a critical point exists the first derivative at that point must be $0$ or undefined, but I wasn't sure if the converse holds true - whether the first derivative being 0 always implies there's a critical point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The critical points are **defined** to be the points where the derivative is zero or undefined.  Whether those points are turning points or not is up in the air.  For instance, the derivative of $f(x)=x^3$ is zero when $x=0$, but $(0,0)$ is neither a local maximum nor a local minimum point of $f$.

Comment: Great explanation! THank you